How to build an automated check to make sure developers do not use System.currentTimeMillis()
I have a Java app built on SpringBoot and compiled with Maven.
Developers quite frequently use "System.currentTimeMillis()" or "new Date()" to get the current time. However, in my application, the current date needs to be taken from a "SystemInfoService". Having such a service makes it possible to mock that service and so we can build unit tests that have predefined "current time"s. Only "SystemInfoService" is allowed to use "System.currentTimeMillis()" but other classes are not.
How can I automate the check that developers don't use "System.currentTimeMillis()" or "new Date()" in their code?
Of course, the final line of defense against this is Peer Reviews but I need an automated way to check this to avoid re-opens as much as possible. The more you automate, the less you have to think about it and the less that can slip through.
Can this be checked with unit tests? Maybe an architecture check tool that can be integrated into the CI/CD pipeline?

Checkstyle will do what you want.  In particular, its RegexpSinglelineJava check.  Checkstyle can and should be invoked in a late phase of the build process itself.

I would only ever consider https://errorprone.info for this, but this has devolved into a library suggestion question.

I have 2 option for you 1, Checkstyle, light weight, can config by your own. Option 2, SonarLint, I recommend this more because with checkstyle you need to run, clean, validate it before using, with plugin SonarLint implenent directly in your idle, run while coding, this will help Developer see the warning right at the time they write the code.

To prevent developers from using System.currentTimeMillis() or new Date() (except through your SystemInfoService), you can automate the check using Checkstyle. Here's a simple way to set it up:
Add Checkstyle to Your Project:
First, you need to add Checkstyle to your Maven build. In your pom.xml, add this plugin:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>src/main/resources/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Create a Checkstyle Configuration:
Then, create a checkstyle.xml file in src/main/resources that will catch calls to System.currentTimeMillis() and new Date():
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <!-- Block System.currentTimeMillis() -->
        <module name="IllegalMethodCall">
            <property name="illegalClassNames" value="java.lang.System"/>
            <property name="illegalMethodNames" value="currentTimeMillis"/>
        </module>

        <!-- Block new Date() -->
        <module name="IllegalMethodCall">
            <property name="illegalClassNames" value="java.util.Date"/>
            <property name="illegalMethodNames" value="&lt;init&gt;"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>

Run Checkstyle in CI/CD:
To make sure the rule is always enforced, add Checkstyle to your CI/CD pipeline (like Jenkins, GitHub Actions, etc.). This will automatically flag any commits that use System.currentTimeMillis() or new Date().
